# NSLayoutConstraint re-activates by itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I created a `strong` constraint for a `UILabel` in a `.xib` file and an outlet for it.

In my code, I set `self.constraint.active = NO`, but after the application loads, when I open the `Debug View Hierarchy`, the same constraint is active.

I tried setting it in `viewDidLoad`, `updateViewConstraints` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to no avail.

I also created a `NSLayoutConstraint` subclass, overwrote the `setActive:` method and put a breakpoint in it, but only my code triggered it.

Comment: what do you mean re-activates it self? what is the constraint about?

Comment: @giorashc, Wait a bit, I hit `enter` to add a tag from the popup window and it decided to post the question instead -_-

Comment: Where in your code are you setting active to `NO`? Also, is your outlet `weak` or `strong`? I believe constraint outlets must be `strong`.

Comment: @Hodson, Updated my question.

Comment: might be obvious but did you connect the constraint to your xib outlet?

Comment: @giorashc :))) Yes, otherwise, my breakpoint wouldn't have been triggered. But I did also check if it's `nil` or not.

Comment: What happens if you try setting it to `NO` in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Hodson, It works! But it makes no sense. Why is there another layout pass after `viewDidAppear:`?

Comment: I don't have time right now to dig into the details. You may be able to get it to work by keeping the code in `viewDidLoad` but I think you have to make a call to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `setNeedsLayout` after you change the active state. I can never remember which to call or if you're meant to call both though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When playing with constraints I advise to do it as late as possible. Depending on your case, it might be as early as `viewDidLoad`.

Whatever you end up doing, you can force a refresh with a `layoutIfNeeded` call.

You could, if I'm not mistaken, disable your constraint and then force an update of constraints / layout ( `updateConstraints` `setNeedsLayout`) and then call `layoutIfNeeded`. But I think you only need to modify your constraint and doing so will automatically set your view to relayout itself whenever it has the time OR when you call `layoutIfNeeded`.

Either way, try with just these two lines, otherwise, add the ones I put between parenthesis.

I'm not gonna lie, sometimes constraints are part iOS, part skill, part black magic.